# Convert level columns to parent ID

Tags: sql-server

Please see picture for my case

[image]

I need to set column parent ID for records that are on a sublevel of the one above.

Could anyone assist me with a MSSQL script for solving this issue turning multilevel to parent id?

I have found a similar question here:

[Generate a parent-child hierarchy from table with levels paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086980/generate-a-parent-child-hierarchy-from-table-with-levels-paths)

but I have failed to use it for my problem.

Comment: Sample data and desired results (IN TEXT) would be helpful

Comment: I want to set parent_ID = 5428 for record with ID nr 5429 and so on...

Comment: https://easyupload.io/2b72zq for excel file

Comment: I can't imagine there are many folks willing to download a  random file.  There are many folks who are willing to assist (myself included), but you need to provide a SMALL data sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct and it's clearly a durty query but I think it can work for a 1 time use to populate the column.

```
SELECT   ID, parent_ID =  
  CASE  
     WHEN level_2_EN_DESC IS NULL THEN NULL
     WHEN level_3_EN_DESC IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID FROM table_category_product tcp2 where tcp.level_1_EN_DESC = tcp2.level_1_EN_DESC AND tcp2.level_2_EN_DESC IS NULL)
     WHEN level_4_EN_DESC IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID FROM table_category_product tcp2 where tcp.level_1_EN_DESC = tcp2.level_1_EN_DESC AND tcp.level_2_EN_DESC = tcp2.level_2_EN_DESC AND tcp2.level_3_EN_DESC IS NULL)
     WHEN level_5_EN_DESC IS NULL THEN (SELECT ID FROM table_category_product tcp2 where tcp.level_1_EN_DESC = tcp2.level_1_EN_DESC AND tcp.level_2_EN_DESC = tcp2.level_2_EN_DESC AND tcp.level_3_EN_DESC = tcp2.level_3_EN_DESC AND tcp2.level_4_EN_DESC IS NULL)
     WHEN level_6_EN_DESC IS NULL THEN ...
     WHEN level_7_EN_DESC IS NULL THEN ...
     ELSE NULL
  END,  
FROM table_category_product tcp
```

if you can send a SQL Script to generate a sample of data I can try to work on a full answer.

Comment: please see linked script https://easyupload.io/tfb9au